# Scroll Through Android app using appium-Javascript

Tags: android, scroll, appium, webdriver-io, automation-testing

I am doing automation testing using appium, webdriverio, nodejs and I want to set elements value after scrolling, how can I do it?
I have already tried MoveTo, touchAction,scrollIntoView methods on webdriverio documentation but unable to do it.

Comment: You tried await browser.touchAction({
      action: 'moveTo', x: x, y: y
     }); with x & y being the coordinates obtained with getLocation() and it didn't work?

Comment: yeah it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me works these:

```
await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(".*:id/new_supplier_icdph_value"))');

await driver.pause(3000);
const elem = await $('~your_accessibility_id')
await elem.setValue('yourValue')
```